# How to reuse Fragment instace in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in my app, this viewpager contains 10 same fragments with different arguments. Using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as the viewpager's adapter. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` pre-make new instance when a page are selected and then destroy it. But I don't need 10 instances. 3 is enough. When user scroll to right, most left fragment can be reused, because GC are expensive. How to achieve it?

Comment: Hello YaoPB, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10), this will retain all 10 fragments added to FragmentStatePagerAdapter in memory. But this also has a performance implication if the layout files of these fragmnets are complex as they all will stay in memory, optimize it to your need https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setoffscreenpagelimit

Answer (score 0):

When you override the `getItem` function of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, maintain a reference to each of the fragments, and instantiate them only if null:

```
private MyFragment myFragment0, myFragment1, myFragment2, ...;

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if (myFragment0 == null) {
                myFragment0 = new MyFragment();
            }

            return myFragment0;
        case 1:
            if (myFragment1 == null) {
                myFragment1 = new MyFragment();
            }

            return myFragment1;
        case 2:
            if (myFragment2 == null) {
                myFragment2 = new MyFragment();
            }

            return myFragment2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Each of the 10 fragments will only be instantiated once, and each of the 10 fragments will only be instantiated once the user is 1 swipe away from viewing it.

Calling `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10)` like a different user suggested has a similar effect, but it actually results in instantiating all 10 fragments as soon as you set the adapter, which is likely to freeze the app for a short while and therefore not recommended.

Comment: it does not works.10 times instantiation is expensive。i mean only 3 times instantiation at most.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, unless your fragment instance has a ton of properties, destroying and creating the instances shouldn't be much of a problem. (Especially considering modern android devices with high power CPU and RAM)

But to answer your 'how to achieve' question...

1. You need a pool to manage the fragment instances. This will create, retain, and destroy (when necessary) the fragment instances.
2. Whenever `ViewPagerAdapter.getItem()` is called, get a fragment instance from the pool and return it.
3. If the pool has less than 3 instances, create one and return it. Otherwise, return an instance that is no longer used.
4. To determine an instance that is no longer used, keep track of which fragment instance represents which page, what the current page is, and which way the page is about to be viewed.

Now this is basic logic behind it, but is it really worth implementing all (especially #4).

I'm really sorry that I could not show you the actual code snippets since I've never tried to implement such way.

Hope it helps.